# Problems with validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have 2 models

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
   with_options :if => :is_active? do |p_active|
      p_active.validates :avatar, :presence => true
  end

  with_options :if => :isnt_diavoleria? do |p_active|
    p_active.validates :color, :presence => true
  end
  def is_active?
    self.product.active
  end

  def isnt_diavoleria?
    a = (self.is_active? and self.product.section_id != 5)
    a
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :variants, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants
end
```

If i change the attribute section_id or active of a product and save, the validations of the model variant are executed with the old values of  section_id and active.
Why?

How  can i do the validations with the new values?

Comment: To give a more credible answer we'd need an example of the code where you read the objects and where you change them ( I think Frederick Cheung is on the right track here )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by default a pair of `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations don't know that they are the inverse of each other. So when you

```
product.section_id = 23
product.save
```

then inside your validation, the variant goes

```
self.product
```

and actually fetches that from the database again, which obviously doesn't have your unsaved change.

You should be able to  fix this by adding the `:inverse_of` flag to your associations, i.e.

```
class Variant < AR::Base
  belongs_to :product, :inverse_of => :variants
end
class Product < AR::Base
  has_many :variants, :inverse_of => :products
end
```

One day rails will have an identity map which should make this sort of stuff less error prone (it is in rails 3.1 but disabled because of subtle associated bugs if i remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do what @thoferon is suggesting (assuming you aren't doing taking nested attributes for products or something) or make sure all changes to the product are happening through the association object so it is up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are modifying a product through another Ruby object. The product referenced by the variant is still holding the old values. I don't know if this is what you're doing but it could be the case.

A solution could be to reload the product before validation.

```
class Variant
  before_validation do
    self.product.reload
  end
end
```